# Is there a NO-OP tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a tag that i can use to mark out a position in the html, which i can then find later using JQuery. However, I need the tag to be as useless as possible: even empty divs and spans can cause the layout to change depending on the CSS rules you set. For that matter, even rubbish tags that html doesn't understand seem to acquire styles from css, and I don't think there is any way to find comments via DOM traversal?

This tag will be used to mark out the start and end of a chunk of HTML to be Ajaxed. I do not want to wrap the whole chunk in a div or span (which i what i'm doing now), because this can affect how the CSS cascades and i want the fact that the html is marked out as a chunk to be completely transparent to the programmer (me).

Any ideas?

edit: I just thought of using empty script tags. Those *should* be completely inert and invisible. I shall look into it

edit: How could i forget about display: none? stupid stupid stupid

Comment: can you use the attribute on the tag in question? I mean location should mean some sort of element you're looking for...

Comment: Yes, comment nodes _are_ part of the DOM tree.  You can access them and manipulate them just like all the other node types.

Comment: What does "start and end of a chunk of HTML to be Ajaxed" mean? Are you talking about initially blank content that will be populated via an Ajax call, or intially full content that is some sort of data to be submitted via Ajax, or...? Should the user see the content at any point in the process?

Comment: @nnnnnn: I mean i have two tags, `<tag></tag> ... <tag></tag>`. In between is stuff i (might) want to replace on an ajax request, potentially multiple times.

@Eimantas: I am doing that now. However, ideally the replaceable area would be able to contain absolutely anything, which would include plain text, which is why i want to bound it as such
@Ray Toal: You can??? I shall go investigate.

Comment: @Li - OK, then I would think `<div style="display:none"></div> ... <div style="display:none"></div>` would work. But it still seems a weird sort of requirement when putting your content in a single `<div>` and styling that `<div>` appropriately should do the trick.

Comment: @nnnnnn: It is a bit of a strange requirement, but i want all this to have absolutely 0 impact on my page w.r.t. layout, css, everything. I want it to be completely 100% invisible to me, and worrying about properly styling and dealing with a magical div that gets inserted into the hierarchy, and considering the case where the ajaxable component is inline and needs to be span'd instead of div'd, for every element, is more thought than I am willing to put in =D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Script tags
2. Anchor tags `<a name...>`

Comment: Script tags work great. As it turns out, Anchor tags do not; they can take on margins/etc. from the css and mess up your layout (even when empty)

Answer (score 3):

Can you use comment tags: `<!-- whatever -->`? Parser would allow you to distinguish it.

Comment: But is there some easy way to pull them out using jquery's $(''), or some other one-liner? I want to leverage off other people's work as much as possible =)

Comment: Someone wrote a plugin for this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm

Comment: this plugin is not what he is looking for.  he'd have to know where to look for the comment, where as he needs the comment to know where to look for something else, presumably.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're talking about trying to use comments or `<script>` tags it seems that you don't want the content of your "chunk" to be visible to the user? If so, why can't you just wrap it like this:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="myChunk1">...your content...</div>
```

That won't interfere with the layout. If you have multiple "chunks" on the page use `class="chunkClass"` instead of setting the style inline.

Using jQuery you can easily get access to the content, delete the whole chunk, replace it, make it visible, etc.

If one extra `<div>` or `<span>` is screwing up your layout there's probably something else going on with your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

[Responding to the title, not the actual scenario] If PHP is involved, <?php  ?> makes a dandy no-op tag; e.g.,

> <p>No space between this<?php
>
> ?>that.</p>

will render as

No space between thisthat.

(except this facility does not do the Right Thing for embedded PHP multi-line tags, so the preceding was coded without any embedded newlines).